# How to get this output in spark sql?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How do I get this output of listing all the movies for each year using spark.sql?

```
Ouput:
(1988,{(Rain Man),(Die Hard)})
(1990,{(The Godfather: Part III),(Die Hard 2),(The Silence of the Lambs),(King of New York)})
(1992,{(Unforgiven),(Bad Lieutenant),(Reservoir Dogs)})
(1994,{(Pulp Fiction)})
```

this is the json data:

```
{ "id": "movie:1", "title": "Vertigo", "year": 1958, "genre": "Drama", "summary": "A retired San Francisco detective suffering from acrophobia investigates the strange activities of an old friend's wife, all the while becoming dangerously obsessed with her.", "country": "USA", "director": { "id": "artist:3", "last_name": "Hitchcock", "first_name": "Alfred", "year_of_birth": "1899" }, "actors": [ { "id": "artist:15", "role": "John Ferguson" }, { "id": "artist:16", "role": "Madeleine Elster" } ] }
```

Here is the code I have tried:

```scala
val hiveCtx = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc) 
val movies = hiveCtx.jsonFile("movies.json") 
movies.createOrReplaceTempView("movies")
val ty = hiveCtx.sql("SELECT year, title FROM movies")
```

Please help me find the correct query.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: How are you storing this data? Can you please include all code you have used to get to this point?

Comment: create hivectx:                                                                                          
 val hiveCtx = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)                                             val movies = hiveCtx.jsonFile("movies.json")                                                                          movies.createOrReplaceTempView("movies")                                                                        now i need a sql query to get the ouptut listing all movies for each year                           
 val ty = hiveCtx.sql("SELECT year, title FROM movies")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get something similar without using spark.sql. You can simply perform the operation on the dataframe itself:

```scala
movies.groupBy($"year").agg(concat_ws("; ", collect_list($"title"))).show
```

Dataset used:

```
{ "id": "movie:1", "title": "Vertigo", "year": 1958, "genre": "Drama", "summary": "A retired San Francisco detective suffering from acrophobia investigates the strange activities of an old friend's wife, all the while becoming dangerously obsessed with her.", "country": "USA", "director": { "id": "artist:3", "last_name": "Hitchcock", "first_name": "Alfred", "year_of_birth": "1899" }, "actors": [ { "id": "artist:15", "role": "John Ferguson" }, { "id": "artist:16", "role": "Madeleine Elster" } ] }
{ "id": "movie:2", "title": "The Blob", "year": 1958, "genre": "Drama", "summary": "The Blob", "country": "USA", "director": { "id": "artist:3", "last_name": "Hitchcock", "first_name": "Alfred", "year_of_birth": "1899" }, "actors": [ { "id": "artist:15", "role": "John Ferguson" }, { "id": "artist:16", "role": "Madeleine Elster" } ] }
```

Output:

```
+----+----------------------------------+
|year|concat_ws(; , collect_list(title))|
+----+----------------------------------+
|1958|                 Vertigo; The Blob|
+----+----------------------------------+
```